# How can I get ID of different values of one column in a MySQL table by Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a „time” column in MySQL table which is declared as String column. The time values are like: '2017-07-02 00:00:05'. I created a Jframe where the time can be chosen by JcomboBoxes:

```
    public static String StartTime;
       public static String EndTime;
        public TimeChooser() {
        initComponents();
        Statement st = null;
         String query = "SELECT time FROM ceiloTable";
          try{
            Connection con = getConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
            jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("time"));
            jComboBox2.addItem(rs.getString("time"));
            }
          }catch(Exception e){}

       private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        StartTime = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();}
     private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        EndTime = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();}
```

I give these strings to the java code where I use the Select statement:

```
NewJFrame_DB jframe = new NewJFrame_DB();
        jframe.STime = StartTime;
        jframe.ETime = EndTime;
```

When I use these strings in the select statement:

```
PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ceiloTable WHERE time BETWEEN " + STime + " AND " + ETime);
```

I get the following error after run the code:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:05 AND 2017-07-02 00:01:57' at line 1
```

It seems that I cannot use these strings because they contains space and colons. Due to this matter I would like to use the ID as primary key of StartTime and EndTime but I do not know how I can get their ID? Can someone let me know how I can get ID of StartTime and EndTime? Thank you for your response in advance!

Comment: Consider escaping the dates with `'` , better yet, consider using the `?` placeholders system from `PreparedStatement` by using `setString` method .  e.g :  `"SELECT * FROM ceiloTable WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ? "` , `statement.setString(1,STime)`,  `statement.setString(2,ETime)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `time` field in DB is `string(varchar)` and not `datetime`, then using BETWEEN clause will do lexicographic comparison and not chronological, may result inaccurate or incorrect result, depending on your `datetime` format. Suggested to use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ceiloTable WHERE STR_TO_DATE(time,'%m/%d/%Y %r') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?,'%m/%d/%Y %r') AND STR_TO_DATE(?,'%m/%d/%Y %r')");
statement.setString(1,STime);
statement.setString(2,ETime);
statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works with `STR_TO_DATE(time,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s')` and `STR_TO_DATE(?,'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s')`.